# Sensor data collection C daemon dilemma

Tags: c++, mysql, c, udp, sensors

Here is the problem. Sensor boards send 31 bytes of data 3 times a second in various UDP packet sizes. For example:

```
1st packet 6 bytes
2nd packet 8 bytes
3rd packet 1 byte
4th packet 5 bytes
5th packet 5 bytes
6th packet 6 bytes

1st packet 4 bytes
2nd packet 5 bytes
3rd packet 1 byte
4th packet 7 bytes
5th packet 3 bytes
6th packet 6 bytes
7th packet 5 bytes
```

There are multiple sensor boards that send data from different locations.

Issue I have is how to sequence detect multiple sensor board data as its being received. I can sequence detect one board since its sequential. But do not know how to sequence detect each sensor boards data and then store an average of every 100 sets of data for each sensor board. Without having a struct that collects data for each unique sender until a buffer of 31 bytes are received to form a whole packet, then store that in another struct until 100 sets are received for each sender, I'm not sure how to do this.

With one device, as I said, I can sequence detect for receiving a whole set of 31 bytes. Data is stored in a mysql database.

Program is in C.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Jason

Comment: Can you explain some more details about the protocol these sensor boards use? For example, how does it deal with packet loss? Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: If the boards all talk to the same port and don't put any identifying info in the packet then you are out of luck. But most UDP implementations do include the sender IP - even though it isn't strictly required, so you could detect that

Comment: How is the coalesced data packet constructed from these variously sized data?  For example, only one has a 7 byte message, so it does not seem like the message size determines the type of data.

Comment: Packet loss is not dealt with, that will have to be implemented to overcome UDP lacking connectionless and error checking capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

It's UDP, shouldn't the source port number be part of the packet? You could sequentially build up a 31 byte set of data for each separately, based on the packet's origin.

But, since it's UDP, you can't guarantee that packets are going to come in order. Routing issues can cause packet drops, delays, and all sorts of issues. Those issue are going to be minimal if it's not actually going over the internet, and instead there's just one hop.

If you have no method of modifying the output from these sensors, then I think you're going to have to have multiple receivers so you can sequentially build up a 31-byte packet, and then pass that along to something that combines the data from all the sensors.

Comment: Right, just changing the `recv` into `recvfrom` should do the trick.